# PCA: What does it mean that the number of necessary PCs for a given explanation of variance percentage changes?

Tags: pca

I initially asked this question at stackoverflow, but there was no answers. Someone suggested that I ask the question here, and here it follows.

Say one has a program that performs PCA. The program calculates the number of PCs necessary in order to cover a given share of total variation in the data, e.g. 95 %.

Say the number of PCs necessary in order to cover 95 % of the variance is 10 for the data used at time t=1.

At t=2 we re-run the program with data from t=2. For t=2 the number of PCs necessary in order to cover 95 % of the variance is 5.

Hence the number of necessary PCs in order to cover 95 % of the variance has dropped from 10 to 5 from t=1 to t=2.

**Main question:**

Can we make any conclusions about changes in the data from t=1 to t=2 in this case?

**Example:**

Can we say something like: "Since the number of PCs decreases from t=1 to t=2, there is more correlation in the data at t=1 than at t=2. With more correlation in the data, fewer PCs are needed to cover a given share of the varaince in the data."

Comment: Since "correlation in the data" does not appear to be a well-defined or quantifiable measure, it would be difficult to agree with your example.  Could you clarify what your underlying analytical objectives might be?

Comment: @whuber: Say the covariance matrix is created from stock prices. At t=1 we have one covariance matrix. We perform PCA at t=1 and skip PCs tuil 95 % of the original variation in the data i explained by the remaining PCs. At t=2 we repeat the procedure, calculate a new coarvariance matrix, perform PCA and drop PCs tuil the remaining PCs explain 95 % of the original variance in the data at t=2. For t=1 10 PCs were needed to obtain 95 % explanation of the original data at t=1. At t=2, on the other hand, 5 PCs were needed to obtain 95 % explanation of the original data at t=2. Stock correlation up?

Comment: You're still describing a *procedure* rather than a *goal.*  What exactly are you trying to learn from the data?

Comment: @whuber: I am trying to interpret the fact that the number of principal components in order to obtain 95 % of the original variance changes.  Does the reduction in the number of PCs in order to obtain 95 % of the original variance mean that the stocks in the data have become more correlated?

Comment: Could you add from your comments to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments. If you think of the PC's as *latent variables*, maybe you could say that the variation in the data can be represented by fewer latent variable?